# Converting numpy.meshgrid results to a text file

Tags: python, numpy

I feel like this is a rather straight forward question, but I can't seem to find an answer. I have created a numpy.meshgrid and would like to write the results to a text file. For example:

```
lat = np.arange(32.5,34.5,0.1)
long = np.arange(78.5,76.5,-0.1)

#generate meshgrid
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(-1*long, lat, sparse=True)
```

And then write to text file and get something like the following:

```
 long  lat
-78.5 32.5
-78.5 32.6
-78.5 32.7
-78.5 32.8
-78.5 32.9
-78.5 33.0
.
.
.
-78.5 34.5
-78.6 32.5
.
.
.
-76.5 34.5
```

Comment: Why generate a meshgrid?

Comment: @JoeIddon because I thought it was actually generating what I am asking for, but I don't think I 100% understand it's function. If there is a better way to get my result, I welcome suggestions!

Comment: Have you looked at `xx` and `yy`?  Does it look anything like the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but it does the trick and it's easy to add additional information to your table:

```
with open('out.dat', 'w') as outf:
    for lat in yy[:,0]:
        for long in xx[0]:
            outf.write("{:+.1f} {:.1f}\n".format(long, lat))
```

You just have to make sure to account for the fact that `xx` and `yy` have different shapes.

This snippet results in `out.dat`:

```
-78.5 32.5
-78.4 32.5
-78.3 32.5
-78.2 32.5
-78.1 32.5
...   ...
```